# Lagrange exercise - Tetrahedron with the smallest volume formed by coordinate planes and additional plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

I am given the following Lagrange Multipliers' problem:

> Find the equation of the plane that goes through $(2,2,1)$ that creates, on the first octant along with the coordinate planes, a tetrahedron with the smallest volume

Being a Lagrange exercise, I must find the function to be minimized and the constraint.

Given that the tetrahedron's volume will be $V = \frac{xyz}{6}$ we already have the function to be minimized. I am not sure, though, how to deal with the constraint, related to the point $P=(2,2,1)$ given.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can formulate the problem as a constrained optimization problem and apply Lagrange multiplier. Express the plane as
$$\frac xa+\frac yb+\frac zc=1$$

It simply means that the normal direction is $\vec { n } =\left<\dfrac 1a,\dfrac 1b,\dfrac 1c\right>.$ This form of the plane is convenient for this problem since it readily shows that the intercepts with $x,y,z$ axis are $a,b,c$ respectively. Therefore the volume of the cutoff tetrahedron is $V(a,b,c)=\dfrac{abc}{6}.$ Now we need to satisfy the constraint
that the plane passes a giving point. Plugging the point $(2,2,1)$ into the plane we get $\dfrac 2a+\dfrac2b+\dfrac1c=1$

So the mathematical model is a constraint optimization problem

$$\begin{cases}min_{a,b,c>0}f(a,b,c)=6V(a,b,c)=abc\\
s.t \mbox{ }g(a,b,c)=\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b+\dfrac1c-1=0\\
 \end{cases}$$

By Lagrange multiplier, taking partial derivatives w.r.t. $a, b, c$ as in

$$\nabla f=\lambda\nabla g$$
We get
$$bc=-2\lambda a^{-2}$$
$$ac=-2\lambda b^{-2}$$
$$ab=\lambda c^{-2}$$
Multiplying respectively $a, b, c$ on both sides of the above three equations, we get
$$abc=-\lambda\frac2a=-\lambda\frac2b=-\lambda\frac1c$$

Since $a, b, c$ are positive, we have $\lambda\ne0.$ So we must have

$$a=b, a=2c$$

Plugging the above into the constraint $\dfrac2a+\dfrac2b+\dfrac1c=1$ we get $a=6,b=6,c=3.$ There for the plane that cuts off the smallest volume is 
$$\frac x6+\frac y6+\frac z3=1\mbox{ or } x+y+2z=1$$

And the smallest cutoff volume is $V(6,6,3)=\dfrac16\times6\times6\times3=18$